# C++ Sprite not displaying - no errors either

Tags: c++, sfml

I'm a bit lost to why my sprite won't display. I get no errors but the image doesn't display on the rendered window.

I load it like this:

`main.cpp`

```
//before main loop
sf::Sprite background = loadBG(theme["Background"]);
//in main loop
window.draw(background);
```

My function and its header is:

`header`

```
sf::Sprite loadBG(std::string);
```

`cpp`

```
sf::Sprite loadBG(std::string img){

sf::Texture texture;   
if (!texture.loadFromFile(img)){
   exit(1);
}

sf::Sprite sprite(texture); 
    return (sprite);
}
```

I have tested the value of `theme["Background"]` and it equals `test.jpg`

Am i missing something to get it to display ?

Comment: What is `theme["Background"]`? An `std::map`?

Comment: Yeh `std::map<string, string> theme`

Comment: IIRC the image goes out of scope so the sprite is drawing blank space

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `sf::Texture` is out of scope.

Try the following code instead (no error checking):

```
void loadBG(sf::Texture& texture, sf::Sprite& sprite, const std::string& img) {
    if(texture.loadFromFile(img))
        sprite.setTexture(texture);
}
```